# Easiest way to change when Bootstrap navbar collapses (using bootstrap gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I've got a rails app using the bootstrap-sass gem. I'd like to change the width the navbar collapses from tablet (979px) to phone (769px). Overriding a media query isn't a tidy solution.

I've edited `@navbarCollapseWidth` in variables.less and built bootstrap, then copied the contents bootstrap-responsive.css into responsive.scss in gems...vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap. Now however, I've lost the ability to update the gem without losing my changes.

What's the best method here? I'd like to make what I think is a simple change but keep my gem update-able. Perhaps using `@import "bootstrap-responsive-mine";` in application.css.scss then manually updating that file when I need to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read some info about [configuration this gem](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)?

> Import "bootstrap" in your SCSS file of choice to get all of Bootstrap's styles, mixins and variables!

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

> Need to configure a variable or two? Simply define the value of the
>   variable you want to change before importing Bootstrap. Sass will
>   respect your existing definition rather than overwriting it with the
>   Bootstrap defaults.

```
$navbarCollapseWidth: 769px;
@import "bootstrap";
```

Or that is not what you need?

Comment: I added `$navbarCollapseWidth: 769px;` before `@import "bootstrap";` but no luck. I also tried running `bundle install` and restarting the server. I tested with `$btnBackground: #000;` and that worked just fine. Checked github - it's indeed a bug. https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/203